# Is there a better method for affixing UPVC floor trim to skirting, other than the adhesive tape provided?

Tags: floor, trim

Can anyone recommend a better method of affixing UPVC (e.g. Homelux) floor trims to skirting other than the adhesive tape provided?

Can you mechanically affix them or is it just down to adhesives?

Comment: Can you explain better or provide a picture?  Is the skirting tile or wood?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like liquid nails as it dries out to no bond in 10-years or less & prefer Lock-Tite "caulks". But yes, you can nail that stuff. You'll need to pre-drill it (or it will split & explode) for the shank & for the nail head, since you're drilling & filling anyway you may prefer to screw it like I do.

Comment: I would not use fasteners I would buy a small can of cove base adhesive. It is specifically made for this purpose in most cases I don't even mess with the double sided tape but use a little cove base adhesive and it is stuck for good.

Comment: I may fully agree, if I were anyone else. But, the few times I've used UPVC I never had a lay flat tight fit, any adhesive would've been useless.

Comment: I find having it lay flat in a warm room is my best firend, used it a lot on quick flip jobs in the past. If just unrolled it would be just about impossible to get on correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that's great for rubber or vinyl flexible trim and base. But, he's got PVC or UPVC. The hard and rigid stuff that's a direct competitor to wood and even tile.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean plastic roll [wallbase](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/building-materials/flooring-carpeting/wall-base/wallbase-dry-back-93229-4-inchw-x-20-footh-almond?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=Cj0KEQiArK6lBRC5-_jv48uxgrgBEiQAuxdZ9TmxHQU6NdIeK_v_88iCKXyVuk551uIbe4vSXCSEUd8aAkce8P8HAQ):

[image]

Use [Liquid Nails](http://www.liquidnails.com/) or go with real trim.

[image]

---

With the "adhesive tape provided" ? Don't you mean 'the provided adhesive' ? If it comes with a roll of tape it's not the good stuff (if you want to call it that...) If it is the good stuff, with about an eighth inch of goo on its entire backside, what you did wrong was im**proper surface prep** (scarify the surface and then clean it with alcohol). I've never put this stuff in but when it's done correctly, it does NOT come off without destroying the wallboard.

Try not to buy old stock and don't install it when it's cold.